# To display image in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code I have document I want to check whether it is jpeg format, and if it is, it should display the image. Please help me to do this.

```
public string strName = "Sample";
public string strFolder = "Documents";

if (!IsPostBack)
{
   var SearchDoc = (SearchDoc)Session["Documentname"];
   string Imgdocname = SearchDoc.DocumentName;

   string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Imgdocname);
   fileExt = fileExt.ToLower();

   if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".jpg")
   {
      docimg.ImageUrl = "C:\\Search\\" + strName + "\\" + strFolder + "\\" + Imgdocname;
      docimg.Visible = true;

      Response.Write("Success");
   }
   else
   {
      Response.Write("fail");
   }
}

<asp:Image ID="docimg" runat="server" />
```

Comment: what is the problem with this code???

Comment: @ AbdulRahman Ansari first i just check whether it is jpg format than it  need to display the image

Comment: Then the code looks fine just add this line after first line
`fileExt=fileExt.ToLower();`

Comment: AbdulRahman Ansari i tried ur code after url it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Imgdocname);
fileExt = fileExt.ToLower();
if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".jpg")
{
   docimg.ImageUrl = @"C:\\Search\\" + strName + "\\" + strFolder + "\\" + Imgdocname;
}
else
{
   Response.Write("fail");
}

<asp:Image ID="docimg" runat="server" />
```

Comment: it tried it is not working.Actually i check all type of files csv,txt,zip,png,jpg...if it is jpg format it should display the image .

Comment: I have posted the code.When i debug it is perfectly checking the file format but image is not displaying.

Comment: all i can say now is that, plz check if there is image file at the path you passing here

Comment: Yes there is a image file in it or else is there any way to change the code

Comment: check the rendered image URL in browser???
Verify that this URL is correct image location.